# how to get image url in wordpress without any prefix?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

For the wordpress website, I am storing the images to a external server. I have successfully stored the path of the image to wordpress database.

Now, how do i call the images, using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function, i'm getting the url with prefix.

like, http://backslashinfotech.in/tropicanamap/wp-content/uploads/**http://www.backslashinfotech.in/tropicanaapp/images/house-designers-233.jpg**

How do i only get the url without any prefix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are database fields in the options table that path which way it goes to, you can also add plugins for a CDN and have the CDN be the external URL - either should work

Comment: can i do it without purchasing CDN? I have my own server, where all the images are.

Comment: yes - i was using the cdn as the example - instead of using it for a cdn, just point it to your server instead , same principle - removing the prefix to the path :D